Copying of type struct ECommerceMarketplace.OrderItem memory[] memory to storage not yet supported
I am working on creating an E-Commerce Smart Contract. But when I run the migrate command, I'm getting this error:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ECommerceMarketplace {
    struct OrderItem {
        uint256 productId;
        uint256 quantity;
        uint256 price;
    }

    struct Order {
        uint256 id;
        address buyer;
        OrderItem[] items;
        uint256 totalPrice;
        bool isCompleted;
        uint256 createdAt;
        uint256 completedAt;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Order) public orders;
    uint256 public orderCount;
    address public owner;

    event OrderPlaced(uint256 orderId, address buyer, uint256 totalPrice, uint256 createdAt);
    event OrderCompleted(uint256 orderId, uint256 completedAt);

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    function placeOrder(uint256[] memory _productIds, uint256[] memory _quantities, uint256[] memory _prices) public payable {
        require(_productIds.length == _quantities.length && _quantities.length == _prices.length, "Arrays must have the same length");
        
        uint256 totalPrice = 0;
        OrderItem[] memory items = new OrderItem[](_productIds.length);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _productIds.length; i++) {
            uint256 itemTotal = _quantities[i] * _prices[i];
            totalPrice += itemTotal;
            items[i] = OrderItem(_productIds[i], _quantities[i], _prices[i]);
        }

        require(msg.value == totalPrice, "Incorrect payment amount");

        orderCount++;
        uint256 timestamp = block.timestamp;
        orders[orderCount] = Order(orderCount, msg.sender, items, totalPrice, false, timestamp, 0);

        emit OrderPlaced(orderCount, msg.sender, totalPrice, timestamp);
    }

    function completeOrder(uint256 _orderId) public onlyOwner {
        Order storage order = orders[_orderId];
        require(!order.isCompleted, "Order is already completed");

        order.isCompleted = true;
        uint256 timestamp = block.timestamp;
        order.completedAt = timestamp;
        payable(owner).transfer(order.totalPrice);

        emit OrderCompleted(_orderId, timestamp);
    }

    function getOrderDetails(uint256 _orderId) public view returns (address, uint256, bool, uint256, uint256) {
        Order storage order = orders[_orderId];
        require(order.id != 0, "Order does not exist");
        return (order.buyer, order.totalPrice, order.isCompleted, order.createdAt, order.completedAt);
    }

    function getOrderItems(uint256 _orderId) public view returns (uint256[] memory, uint256[] memory, uint256[] memory) {
        Order storage order = orders[_orderId];
        require(order.id != 0, "Order does not exist");
        
        uint256[] memory productIds = new uint256[](order.items.length);
        uint256[] memory quantities = new uint256[](order.items.length);
        uint256[] memory prices = new uint256[](order.items.length);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < order.items.length; i++) {
            productIds[i] = order.items[i].productId;
            quantities[i] = order.items[i].quantity;
            prices[i] = order.items[i].price;
        }

        return (productIds, quantities, prices);
    }
}


Error Message:
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\ECommerceMarketplace.sol

UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct ECommerceMarketplace.OrderItem memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.11.5 (core: 5.11.5)


The issue is due to directly allocating or copying a dynamic array of structs (i.e., Order[] and OrderItem[]) from memory to storage in Solidity. Solidity does not support this kind of operation because of the different ways memory and storage are managed.
Here's the revised placeOrder() function:
function placeOrder(
    uint256[] memory _productIds,
    uint256[] memory _quantities,
    uint256[] memory _prices
) public payable {
    require(
        _productIds.length == _quantities.length &&
            _quantities.length == _prices.length,
        "Arrays must have the same length"
    );

    uint256 totalPrice = 0;

    // Increment order count to get a new orderId
    orderCount++;
    uint256 orderId = orderCount;

    // Create an empty Order struct in storage with an empty array
    Order storage order = orders[orderId];

    order.id = orderId;
    order.buyer = msg.sender;
    order.createdAt = block.timestamp;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _productIds.length; i++) {
        uint256 itemTotal = _quantities[i] * _prices[i];
        totalPrice += itemTotal;

        // Push each OrderItem to the storage array
        order.items.push(
            OrderItem({
                productId: _productIds[i],
                quantity: _quantities[i],
                price: _prices[i]
            })
        );
    }

    require(msg.value == totalPrice, "Incorrect payment amount");

    // Update the totalPrice in the storage
    order.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    order.isCompleted = false;

    emit OrderPlaced(orderId, msg.sender, totalPrice, block.timestamp);
}

